# Sources for learning Computer Networks

Tags: networking, computer-science

I've been recommended Computer Networks, a top-down approach by James Kurose and Keith Ross. Related to that I've heard good and bad critics, I would like ask you what's your opinion. I mean, I expect to know something about this book before spend my money. Thanks!

Comment: Read the FAQ.  That's not the kind of question that SO was created for.

Comment: Why not? I've seen many other questions concerning to specific computing topics asking the same, and those one are accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well IMO, Computer networks by Kurose and Ross has lots of mistakes, actually, its explanation about how TCP works is pretty awful, and the exercises proposed at the end of each chapter are  dispensable. I would recommend the "old classics", I mean something about Andrew S. Tanenbaum (as Bill said), and related to TPC there is a book by Stevens that is pretty useful. I also recommend the book from O'Reilly to learn how DNS works.

EDIT 1:

Another thing I consider is that almost all computer network books are organized in the opposite approach, I mean, they start from the most concrete Layers (such as Physical or Link layer) and they end at the Application Layer, which is the most abstract layer. Perhaps all of those books are wrong, but I feel that would be very strange to be true.

Comment: Thanks andres and bill, perhaps I should buy Tanenbaum book

Answer (score 4):

My favorite book is by Tannenbaum.....

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networks-5th-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/0132126958](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132126958)